# Replacing numbers in the last column of data

Tags: unix

Quick question, should be rather simple for people who know the syntax, the question is what the title says. if i have this as an example:

```
    Something1 hi bye 12
    Cars32 hello bye 23
    Cars32 hello bye 65
    Cars32 hello bye 34
    word hello bye 42
    Cars32 hello bye 32
    Cars32 hello bye 75
    Cars32 hello bye 12
    Cars32 hello bye 42
```

And I want to replace all occurrences of 12 in the last column with 3, and all 42's with 5. How would i go about doing this. Thanks.

Comment: Steps: decide what language you want it (perl, shell script/awk/..., C/C++,...); search how to read file line by line in language of your choice; search how to find/replace; pipe result to file. Done. To be good question for SO you need to do at least one of the above steps yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way, using `awk`:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '\
{
  val = $4;
  if(val == 12) {
    val = 3;
  }else if(val == 42){
    val = 5;
  }
  print $1, $2, $3, val;
}'
```

If you text file is saved as `example.txt`, save this `awk` script as `exampleScript` (and `chmod 777` so that it's executable), then run it as

> cat example.txt | ./exampleScript

Output:

```
Something1 hi bye 3
Cars32 hello bye 23
Cars32 hello bye 65
Cars32 hello bye 34
word hello bye 5
Cars32 hello bye 32
Cars32 hello bye 75
Cars32 hello bye 3
Cars32 hello bye 5
```

Comment: Side note: I usually have to relearn `awk` `sed` and `perl` each time I write in them, so refer to this tutorial: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you do with `awk`:

```
$ awk '$NF==12{$NF=3}$NF==42{$NF=5}1' file
Something1 hi bye 3
Cars32 hello bye 23
Cars32 hello bye 65
Cars32 hello bye 34
word hello bye 5
Cars32 hello bye 32
Cars32 hello bye 75
Cars32 hello bye 3
Cars32 hello bye 5
```

Comment: `$NF` holds the value of last field which is used here for checking and updating.